# How can I access a method from a relative layout class from a popup window with Python Kivy?

Tags: python, methods, kivy

I have been trying to access the method `print_hello` by clicking the popup button in the popup window however, whenever I try to actually execute this part of the code, the interpreter tells me the following

```
     on_press: root.print_hello()
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'PopupMenu' object has no attribute 'print_hello'
```

This is the code of my Python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout 

class MainLayout(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = "Important data from the MainLayout class"
    def print_hello(self):
        print("Hello")

class MyApp(App): # defining the app class
    def build(self): # using MyRelativeLayout in the app
        return MainLayout() # returning MyRelativeLayout
    
MyApp().run()
```

and this is the code of my Kv file:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MainLayout>:
    Button:
        text: "Main Button"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 1}
        on_press: Factory.PopupMenu().open()
        
<PopupMenu@Popup>
    auto_dismiss: True
    title: "Popup Menu"
    size_hint: [0.80, 0.80]
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
    RelativeLayout:
        size_hint: [1, 1]
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 1}
        PopupWindowButton:
            id: line_button
            size_hint: [0.10, 0.10 * root.width / root.height]
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 1}
            text: "Popup Button"
            on_press: root.print_hello()
            
<PopupWindowButton@Button>
    font_size: "15dp"
    background_color: 0, 0.5, 0, 1
```

I just want to be able to call that method from wherever part in my code and that method to belong to the MainLayout class, since in actuality this is just simplified version of the same problem but with much more lines of code and other situations that here would only make reading the code more complex.

Is there any way to access the `print_hello` method by clicking the popup button?

I just tried to execute the method `print_hello` from the MainLayout class by clicking the popup button. However, it seems that because the method doesn't belong to the PopupWindo class, it cannot be executed by clicking the popup button.

Is there any way to access this method by clicking the popup button?

Comment: Try changing `root.print_hello()` to `app.root.print_hello()`.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this a little and this works for me:
.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class PopupMenu(Popup):
    def print_hello(self):
        MainLayout.print_hello(MainLayout)

class MainLayout(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = "Important data from the MainLayout class"
    def print_hello(self):
        print("Hello")

class MyApp(App): # defining the app class
    def build(self): # using MyRelativeLayout in the app
        return MainLayout() # returning MyRelativeLayout
    
MyApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MainLayout>:
    Button:
        text: "Main Button"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 1}
        on_press: Factory.PopupMenu().open()
        
<PopupMenu>
    auto_dismiss: True
    title: "Popup Menu"
    size_hint: [0.80, 0.80]
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
    RelativeLayout:
        size_hint: [1, 1]
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 1}
        PopupWindowButton:
            id: line_button
            size_hint: [0.10, 0.10 * root.width / root.height]
            pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 1}
            text: "Popup Button"
            on_press: root.print_hello()
            
<PopupWindowButton@Button>
    font_size: "15dp"
    background_color: 0, 0.5, 0, 1
```